# Ambiguity with class and model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to define a "Product"-class for my model (.edmx), and I have it in the same folder as the model.

I get: Ambiguity between 'MVCTest.Models.Product.ProductID' and 'MVCTest.Models.Product.ProductID' error

What's needed to do so I can define my classes correctly?

/M

Comment: Why are you trying to recreate a class with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using "Partial class"?  Only really appropriate if it's an extension of the product class I guess.

If this is not what you were looking for then let us know with more information or even code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You could always separate out by namespace. Have one class in one namespace. Although having the same class with the same properties is a bit unusual, and suggests that you need to refactor and create some form of inheritance as griegs suggested.